# Conditional plotting if variable equals a particular string in R

Tags: r, panel-data, plotrix

I have a time series panel dataset similar to the following format, where V1 is character (here A,B,C...) and V2 is numeric(5,8,6...). I have 65 different items in V1 (total of about 50000 odd observations). I am trying to find a way to plot V2 provided V1=A or B and so on. What I can simply do is `plot(V1[1:1065])`, `plot([V1:1066:2085])` and so on but I was looking for a robust way of doing this. Tried something like this:

```
if(V1 == 'A') plot(V2)
```

But since 'if' in R does not accept vectors, it gives an error message, `"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"`

```
V1 V2      Date

A   5   01/01/2014

A   8   08/01/2014

B   6   15/01/2014

C   9   22/01/2014

C   6   29/01/2014

D   3   05/02/2014

-   -   -

-   -   -

-   -   -

-   -   -

X   8   12/03/2014

Y   5   19/03/2014

Z   5   26/03/2014
```

Could anyone please suggest something?

Comment: Do you want 65 separate plots or several/all lines per unique value of V1 combined in one plot?

Comment: Did you `attach` your data? Your use of the column names inside the `if` looks like that. Just note that it is widely discouraged to use `attach` when scripting. Better learn how to subset using `[]` and `$`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am using $ now instead of attach ..

Comment: Good to hear that. Make sure you also check out `?with`, which is also helpful in many situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are all stored in a data.frame called `dd` then you could do

```
plot(V2~Date, data=subset(dd, V1=="A"))
```

That should produce a plot for all the "A" values in V1.